# Bash: more than 1 variable in "For-in" Loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop

example:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4, j in 7 8 9 0
do
echo $i"="$j
done
```

output:

```
1=7
2=8
3=9
4=0
```

i know this code will throw you a lot of error right away, but is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in Bash, but you can get your desired output:

```
foo=(1 2 3 4)
bar=(7 8 9 0)

for (( i=0; i<${#foo[@]}; i++ ))
do
    echo "${foo[$i]}=${bar[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: i see... I was just hoping that it exist somehow because of the convenience, unlike the answer that you provided, where we have to create those variables outside, before the loop. so i have a question about `${#foo[@]}` what does the # mean, why it should be in front of foo, and whats @, why it sould be inside []? ive been encountering codes like that and it makes me dizzy.

Comment: `${}` is dynamic variable call syntax. `#` before `foo` ask for the length of the array `foo`, `[@]` returns all items within foo, so we get the actual size of the full array

Comment: okay, so `#`= `length of` and  `@`=`items` and also it only works in `${}` i suppose ...noted it, thanks